# SendMessageW returns "Invalid window handle"

Tags: c++, winapi

Im trying to display an image on a window in c++ and my SendMessageW returns "Invalid window handle".
My SendMessageW function:

```
void ImageWindows() {
   messageResult = SendMessageW(hImageWindow, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hFirstPic); //sending image to window
   //Error check
   if (messageResult == NULL) {
       DWORD error = GetLastError();
       LPTSTR output = NULL;
       FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, error, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR)&output, 0, NULL);
       MessageBox(NULL, output, L"Error. Reason:", MB_OK);
   }
   else {
       MessageBox(NULL, L"Image was assigned correctly!", L"Success", MB_OK);
   }
   //Error check
}
```

my hImageWindow:

```
hImageWindow = CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, NULL, WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP, 100, 100, 517, 450, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL); //Creating main window
```

Im calling the ImageWindows() function at WM_CREATE, but before that I set the value of hFirstPic. I also do an error check while doing that, and it returns no errors. What I get is a blank, white window. I also haven't really found any answers regarding this topic, only one from 10 years ago, but that fix didn't work in my case.

In case its needed, here's my window class:

```
//MAIN WINDOW CLASS
WNDCLASSW wc = {}; //Creating window class
wc.hInstance = hInstance; //Instance of class
wc.lpszClassName = L"mainClass"; //Name of class
wc.lpfnWndProc = wc_callback; //Assigning callback function to class
```

Your help is appreciated, thanks for helping!

Comment: `messageResult == NULL` not mean error in case `STM_SETIMAGE`. this only mean that  no image previously associated with the static control

Comment: have you checked that `hImageWindow ` is not null?

Comment: @RolandasUlevicius Yes, I did, its not null.

Comment: @Rolandas Think you missed something. Read the docs, and RbMm's comment.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/stm-setimage):

> **Return value**
>
> The return value is a handle to the image previously associated with
> the static control, if any; otherwise, it is NULL.

So `messageResult` does not mean failure.The reason for the error `Invalid window handle` is that `hImageWindow` is NULL at the time of `WM_CREATE`, so you cannot use `SendMessageW` at this time.

[image]

You need to create a static control and call the `ImageWindows` function after the window is created. Here is a sample:

```
#include <Windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
HWND hImageWindow;
void ImageWindows() {
    HBITMAP hFirstPic = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"test.bmp", (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    LRESULT messageResult = SendMessageW(hImageWindow, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hFirstPic); //sending image to window
    //Error check
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    if (error != 0) {
        LPTSTR output = NULL;
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, error, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR)&output, 0, NULL);
        MessageBox(NULL, output, L"Error. Reason:", MB_OK);
    }
    else {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Image was assigned correctly!", L"Success", MB_OK);
    }
    //Error check
}
int WINAPI WinMain(_In_  HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_  LPSTR szCmdLine, _In_  int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("hello windows");
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,
        TEXT("the hello program"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    hImageWindow = CreateWindow(L"STATIC", L"background", SS_BITMAP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 300, 300, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    ImageWindows();

    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```